# Ubuntu 12.10 excess boot time

Tags: 12.10

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. But it takes almost forever to boot and show the log on screen. Is it natural?

my bootchart report  https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1uNN.png

Comment: Short question, short answer: NO.

Comment: How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely NOT.

A few suggestions to troubleshoot:

1. If you are able to login (X or terminal/SSH from another), check dmesg output
2. install bootchart http://www.bootchart.org (boot process) to identify the bottleneck
3. Edit /etc/default/grub
   Comment out the following line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Run update-grub to update grub config
This will output more stuff during the boot process, something may ring a bell;-)

HTH

Comment: I used bootchart and disabled some items now everything works fine:-)

Comment: Cool, good to hear;-)